# ¿Cómo replicar funcionalidad de generador de números aleatorios para permalink (de Blogger) en Python?

Tags: python, blogger

Buen día, vengo trabajando con mi blog de Blogger desde ya hace unos 6 meses y tengo un gran problema. Necesito urgentemente poder crear el mismo código que utiliza Blogger para generar un numero "random" (no sé si será random) que pone al final de un enlace ya creado del mismo blog. Por cierto me refiero a la opción de "enlace permanente automático".

He creado mi propio generador de entradas de Blogger en texto plano para poder agregarlos a una copia de seguridad y poder subir hasta 900 entradas en 1 minuto sin ningún limitaciones (Blogger te limita hasta 40 entradas por pensar que eres un robot). Pero una gran limitación exterior es la que menciono.

Su sistema trabaja de esta forma:

Solo crea enlaces de máximo 41 letras o números y excluye cualquier espacio y signo como: `-,@,[,*`,etc y por alguna razón también excluye la palabra en ingles `the` si se encuentra en medio de 2 palabras

Al haber un enlace igual a otro enlace ya creado anteriormente lo que hace Blogger es aumentarle un `_` y uno o dos o números que no sé si serán random. Yo imagino que sí porque da cualquier número al azar de un dígito o dos dígitos.

Por ejemplo:

`hola-soy-un-enlace.html` -> Este sería el primer enlace

`hola-soy-un-enlace_9.html` --> Este sería el segundo enlace igual pero con el `_X` agregado por Blogger para que no haya fallas. (cabe recalcar que podría mostrarlo como `_53` u otros numero al azar)

Yo busco crear ese mismo generador que utiliza Blogger para crear el número `_X` o `_XX` o `_XXX`

Sé que no estoy dando mucha información. He buscado acerca de cómo funciona pero no he encontrado nada acerca de eso. Sé que crear un generador random que me da del 1 al 99 es fácil. Pero hacer uno que cumpla el mismo funcionamiento de Blogger es lo que busco en lenguaje Python.

Quizá alguna persona de aquí también trabaje con Blogger y sepa algo acerca de esto. Si es así por favor comparte la información. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Generar el mismo sistema que utiliza blogger para crear `_XX` cuando un enlace es igual a uno anteriormente ya creado

Comment: Creo que lo que estás pidiendo supondría el fin de la criptografía como la conocemos. El hecho de que sea "aleatorio" es por definición...eso, aleatorio. Generar el mismo número con el mismo algoritmo dejaría entonces de ser aleatorio sino determinado por unas condiciones de inicio establecidas y sería como poco polémico por parte de Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de un aleatorio te sugeriría crear un incrementable y agregar siempre tu valor antes del final del título; así nunca vas a repetir tus títulos sin importar si es muy largo el título o es corto. Tomando en cuenta que el maximo del titulo es 41 te dejo un ejemplo de como te podría servir.

```
aux = 0
all_entries['titulo-capitulo-1', 'nombre-de-serie-muy-largo-para-el-titulo-episodio-1', 'nombre-de-serie-muy-largo-para-el-titulo-episodio-2']
for entry in all_entries:
    entry_name = entry[0:41-(len(str(aux))+1)]+"_"+str(aux)
    aux+=1
```

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 1):

en ese aspecto, puedes usar primero una lista con los nombre de los enlaces ya generados, por ejemplo

```
lista_nombres = [ "articulo_uno", "articulo_2" ]
```

y de ahi con el nombre listo generado, solo comparas

```
nuevo_nombre = "articulo_uno"

while nuevo_nombre in lista_nombres:
    prefijo = str(tugeneradoraleatorio())
    nuevo_nombre = nuevo_nombre + "_" + prefijo
```

y con eso tienes algo parecido, no se si es lo que busques

saludos

puedes incluir un while para revisar que el prefijo no haya sido usado antes

Comment: Es lo que haria, Sin embargo busco que el generador aleatoreo cumpla el mismo funcionamiento de Blogger. Y es que el gran problema es que no se como funciona el generador aleatorio de Blogger. Cada vez que se actualiza el segundo enlace igual al primero. genera un nuevo numero ya sea de uno `_X` o dos dígitos `_XX`. Si hay un tercer enlace igual al primero enlace que obviamente no tiene un `_X` porque es el primero, Ese tercero tambien se crea un `_XX` con otro numero aleatoreo. Eh visto que algunos llegan hasta 3 digitos osea `_XXX`

Comment: Seria bueno saber cuales son tus input, por ejemplo quieres generar el enlace usando el titulo del tema? tienes registro de los enlaces creados previamente, por ejemplo para validar el enlace que creaste ayer, como por ejemplo en una base de datos?? he creado sistemas similares, pero me serviria saber donde estoy parado, por ejemplo, si este lo tienes en un host propio y tu almacenas tus propios articulos, etc

Comment: Blogger crea los enlace automaticos apartir de los titulos, Yo podria modificar los enlaces personalmente pero tomaria tiempo, Cree un programa para darme facilidad y agregar posts masivamente, entre  500 o 1500 (Los posts son de Episodios de series). El problema es cuando el titulo es muy grande por el nombre de la serie. Entonces no abarca el `Episodio 1`, Sino `nombre-de-sere-grande.html` (ya que solo acepta hasta 41 letras o numeros), entonces el siguiente episodio generaria un enlace conel numero random  `enlace-anterior_XX` o `_X` o `_XXX`

Comment: por eso no puedo agregar series de títulos grandes masivamente. un enlace que lleve todo titulo mas elnumero de episodio seria asi. `nombre-de-serie-corto-episodio-1` (de 41 letras o numero, o menos), Entonces detro del html me las arregla para poner en el boton de siguiente capitulo el mismo nombre de la serie mas `episodio-2`. Pero cuando el titulo es mas grande y no muestra el `èpisodio-1` es el problema ya que el enlace seria como el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: Agrego posts masivamente mediante las copias de seguridad de blogger en xml, `html.escape()`. Así que ningún post esta en el blog hasta el momento en que sea subida mediante la importación. Uso el host de blogger, Solo cuento con dominio propio